# ImageButton does not resize the image

Tags: android, android-imagebutton

Why `ImageButton` does not resize the image?

```
<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="250dp"
    android:background="null"
    android:src="@drawable/r" />
```

[Preview Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pvLML.png)

[image]

> Image name is r.png

Comment: android:scaleType="fitCenter"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `android:scaleType="centerCrop"`

```
<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="250dp"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/r" />
```

If you don't want to crop it, then use `android:scaleType="fitCenter"` instead